# Can we restrict the activation of any child node under jcr:content?

Tags: aem

Can we restrict the activation of any child node under jcr:content ?

Lets just say the structure is:

- testpage

  - jcr:content

    - test1
    - test2
    - test3

So when I activate the page from sidekick, I do not want test3 node to be published. Can we achieve this??

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: While I can't answer your question directly, it might be helpful to know what you're trying to achieve. Maybe there's an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually activation would work at the cq:Page level so only the page would be activated and not individual nodes.  I guess you mean that you want some of the content/nodes be on the author only.  I see two ways of tackling this:

- Option 1: You move the author-only content to a location outside of the site page content branch and reference the content from a component on your page.
- Option 2: You set the "Agent User Id" to a special user for replication and [add an ACL](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/AccessControl#How_Resource-based_ACLs_are_stored) to test3 that denies access to the node.  To that user the node will not exist.
- Option 3: You activate the test3 node to the publish instance but the component that renders it can choose not to based on the [WCMMode](https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/WCMMode.html)

**Option 1** would probably be the simplest to manage.  You haven't described what you're trying to achieve but you could either create a separate (non-activable) page and reference it in your component using a path specified in the component dialog.  Or perhaps your component could create a 'shadow' structure at a location somewhere outside of the page.

**Option 2** is probably closest to what you asked for.
The easiest way to create an ACL on test three is to select the node in CRXDE Lite, select the "Access Control" and then grant/deny access for a specific user/group. Here is an example:

[image]

This will create a special rep:policy node under test3 which will contain a list of allow/deny nodes.

It is also possible to add this ACL [programmatically through the API](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/AccessControl#API_for_setting_resource-based_ACLs) or replicate the content structure created in CRXDELite in a content package if you are creating the content in the development environment.

**Option 3** is possible if you are using a custom component of your own.  You can decide not to render the content for that node if the WCMMode == DISABLED for example.  This will show when authoring but not when on the publish. Here is some more [information on detecting wcm modes](http://labs.sixdimensions.com/blog/2013-04-02/what-my-cq-mode/).

Comment: Thanks for your response @diffa .

I have few doubts though, which are:

Option 1: If I move the content to a location outside site page content branch and reference the content by drag/drop a component on my page, I guess that component parsys node will be created again under site page content node. So in this case again it will be published. Correct me if I am wrong please.

Option2: How can we add an ACL to test3 ? test3 is not a cq:page type, so when we open the CQ5 security console and try to set the ACL it only shows  cq:page type of nodes.

Comment: I have updated the answer to give some more detail on adding ACL to test3.  CRXDELite will allow you to set ACL at node level, as you say CQ security console will allow only at page level.  I'm not sure I understand your question RE Option 1.

Comment: You mentioned that test3 is author reference material in the comments of @user1723204 's answer.  You may find it is easiest to still push this content to the publish instance, making your page the same everywhere it is replicated, but just not render the content when on the publish instance.

Answer (score 0):

if you make your subnodes subpages you can do this. then you can include the content of those subpages within your main page.

that said, why wouldn't you want test3 node to be published?

Comment: Because test3 is the part of content which is a reference material for the author.